# Solving the nested tables problem in relational databases

Tags: database-design

I'm coming from a non-SQL database (MongoDB), and I'm building up a new project, but with MySQL (a relational Database).

I'm making a restaurant system, and in this system, there's a page where you can create a product and describe its ingredients.

In MongoDB, (non-SQL database), you can make this schema for your document, (I'll describe it with JSON just to give the point):

```js
// imagine this is a document of a product stored in the products collection
{
  name: "Burger",
  price: 200,
  ingredients: [
   { name: 'tomato', qty: 2 }, // qty: ie quantity
   { name: 'cheese', qty: 1 },
   { name: 'bread', qty: 2 },
   { name: 'meat', qty: 1 },
  ]
}
```

In an SQL relational database, however, you'll have to create something similar to this:

[image]

At a first glance, it looks ugly, but after thinking for a bit, now I'm starting to get used to it.

Firstly, I want to ask a question regarding this approach:

- **Is it the way to go for this problem?**

I'm sure you have come across this scenario hundreds of times.

Second, I have another question:

Now the user have pressed the "create" button to create his product, and he sent the request to the server to process this request,

How am I going to insert these rows into the database?!

Is it by doing a **for loop** and sending **5** requests to the database:

1. the first request, is to create the row with the **ID#1** in the **product-ingredients** table.
2. the second request, is to create the row with the **ID#2** in the **product-ingredients** table.
3. the third request, is to create the row with the **ID#3** in the **product-ingredients** table.
4. the fourth request, is to create the row with the **ID#4** in the **product-ingredients** table.
5. the fifth and final request, is to create the row with the **ID#1** in the **products** table.

> This looks crazy, a little bit.

That's what my brain is saying.

It's why I'm particularly asking this question.

Later, there will an update product page, and the similar **for loop** with a bunch of requests is going to be executed on the database.

The question now is **HOW**.

I appreciate everyone who's going to take my *brain hand* into the world of relational databases.

Comment: I'm not sure if this information will change the type of the answer, but I'm using nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what the others said, to help fill some gaps:

> ...sometimes say the ingredients are 30 ingredients, am I going to send 30 requests to the database just to create this product?

Like Akina said, it depends, but if none of the 30 ingredients exist yet, then yes one way is to execute a separate `INSERT` statement for each ingredient. But depending on how your application is architected, you could batch those `INSERT` statements together in the same batch so only one request is needed to be made to the database at a time. It is good practice to not make too many extra unnecessary requests to the database, when reasonably possible.

Furthermore, in some database systems, you can use a `BULK INSERT` method when the number of `INSERT` statements is a *lot*. That will not only `INSERT` all of the ingredients in one request, but also in a single statement, leveraging the most optimal way to `INSERT` into the table.

> Ok, how much does the 30 requests going to take in practice? Like how many seconds...

Akina mentioned a few milliseconds for a single `INSERT` statement, but even that is an overestimate. 30 ingredients, etc, is a tiny amount of data. It shouldn't take more than a millisecond, and really probably nanoseconds for a single `INSERT` statement to execute. So yes, `INSERT`ing into the table should be very fast, for the amount of data you're talking about.

> if I'm inserting 30 rows, one by one. What's the guarantee that the 30 rows are going to be created successfully.

That's what [transactions](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/a-primer-on-sql-transactions/) are for. They ensure every data manipulation statement (DML) wrapped inside of them are executed atomically - either all or nothing. If one statement errors out, they all rollback. Otherwise they all succeed together.

> omg, this is too complex, and what if the rollback operation itself failed

Not possible. Once a rollback is issued (either automatically by the database system depending on the error, or manually instructed by your code) it must complete. The database system has a log that it uses to ensure atomicity and consistency (which are part of the [ACID principles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of a database system that is ACID compliant - most RDBMS). A rollback command is noted in the log immediately, so if anything happened such as the database server crashing, it would know where it left off when the server is back online so it can resume reconciling back to a valid consistent state of the database.

Comment: Wow, thanks, what are transactions? Can you make a link for explaining them? Do they exist in MongoDB as well?

Comment: @Normal Yes haha, I added a link that goes in depth about transactions probably just before you saw the update on my answer. As far as MongoDB, I'm not sure, most people don't have a need or use NoSQL databases, and data integrity is treated differently there. But I wouldn't doubt they do have some form of them.

Comment: thanks. This is actually what I want. Thanks to Akina and Phill W as well. thanks all.

Comment: Just for reference here, I found them in MongoDB as well [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/)

Comment: @Normal Cool, np! Please see my latest update addressing your concerns about rollbacks too. Basically reading up on the links I provided about transactions and ACID principles should help ease your worries.

Answer (score 1):

? Is it the way to go for this problem?

Short answer - Yes.

> How am I going to insert these rows into the database?!

Insert the product *first*.
Then retrieve the ID automatically assigned to that newly created product row.
*Then* loop through the Ingredients, inserting each in turn, using the new product ID in each one.

> update product page ... The question now is HOW.

It depends on the change.
Changing a single Ingredient within a product might need a single update.
More "side-scale" changes might be easier done by trashing all the ingredients and inserting them anew.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: I'm still confused, isn't it a problem to send multiple requests to the database in a for loop like that?

Comment: Does the people all around the world do this all the time?

Comment: For inserts, it's not a problem. Insert .. Values only allows the creation of one row at a time so it's fast (insert .. select can do more).  
The Killer is loops of selects, because it is *always* faster to do a "wide" select for all the records you want and loop through that result in your code than the "1+N Query" Method of a "narrow" select to get record /identifiers/, followed by a loop that reads each of those records, by its ID (which is fast in itself), but does so for one record after another, after another, after another, after another  ...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it by doing a for loop and sending 5 requests to the database

No. Backward.

1. Firstly, you create a row in `product` table. On the client side.
2. Then you check ingredients for it, and if some ingredient not exists yet - then you create a row in `ingredients table`. Each new row is saved immediately.
3. Then you link them - you create rows for `product-ingredients` table, one row per one ingredient for this product.
4. Finally, you save your work.

In practice - each row created on the step 2 is saved immediately and separately, you need a query per ingredient. Of course you can collect this data and save all newly created ingredients in one query, but this makes no sense in interactive mode. The rows created on the steps 1 and 3 are saved on the step 4. This needs in 3 queries. 1st query saves the product, 2nd query retrieves its udentifier, 3rd saves all relational rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK, sometimes say the ingredients are 30 ingredients, am I going to send 30 requests to the database just to create this product?

Comment: @Normal *sometimes say the ingredients are 30 ingredients* Do you mean that none of these 30 ingredients exist in the ingredients table? If so then, of course, you'd execute 30 queries, each of them create one ingredient row. Or you may collect these data on the client side then save all 30 new ingredients in one query (but, as I have said, this makes no sense). Of course, if all 30 ingredients are present in the table then you do not need in any query.

Comment: Ok, how much does the 30 requests going to take in practice? Like how many seconds, I know it depends on many factors, but imagine I'm on a regular shared server with a good internet connection

Comment: @Normal One simple insert "on a regular shared server with a good internet connection" needs in not more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: Good. Thanks for this answer. Ok, one last question: if I'm inserting 30 rows, one by one. What's the guarantee that the 30 rows are going to be created successfully, what if two or three rows were lost and were not created. Due to a network connection error, for example, or a connection timeout on the server?

Comment: @Normal You must check status for each separate INSERT. Obvious.

Comment: but how to organize these? like say for example, the first 3 success, then one fail, then the afterward ones were all success, but the last one was fail. and so on. How to organize the failed ones

Comment: what to do when one gets failed? how to handle this senario?

Comment: @Normal *what to do when one gets failed? how to handle this senario?* Execute all queries within a transaction, and rollback it if at least one query fails. Or combine all data into one query (which cannot be executed partially).

Comment: omg, this is too complex, and what if the rollback operation itself failed

Comment: @Normal *what if the rollback operation itself failed* This means that your server fails itself, and a problem with lost row is not your main problem...